# Wso2 ESB don't deploy car

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to remove the car of an Aplication.

I removed the .car by management console and removing the file in  wso2esb-4.0.3/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps but wso2 dont put nothing in the log and dont remove the artifacts, I cant shutdown the server.

When I remove de .car and upload the file again the server dont re-deploy anything

The initial problem was that some artifacts had disapeared from management console, but the .car was deployed, a other instance of the .car are in the temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue [1] and fixed from WSO2 ESB 4.5.0. I think its recommended to use the latest version of the product since in that case many bugs fixed and many new features are added to the product. You can find the latest distribution of WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 latest release here [2]

Hope this will help you.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-940

[2] http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem too. It can also happen when you have deactivated a proxy within the web console.

- Be sure all components from the specific .car file are running.
- Uninstall the application (within the web-console)
- Wait until all components are gone

If this is not working - you need to stop the server and remove all components (from that .car) from the file system manually. We did that a couple of times and it worked. (search for all affected components and remove them).

We finally solved the issue by upgrading to a new version of WSO2 ESB.